# Truffle migration error using powershell

Tags: json-rpc, truffle

When I write out truffle migrate, I get the following error line with a list of other directory paths.
Error: Invalid JSON RPC Response: ""

This is my deploy contracts file:

```
var ConvertLib = artifacts.require("./ConvertLib.sol");
var MetaCoin = artifacts.require("./MetaCoin.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
 // deployer.deploy(ConvertLib);
 // deployer.link(ConvertLib, MetaCoin);
 // deployer.deploy(MetaCoin);
  deployer.deploy(HelloWorld);
};
```

I am unsure as to what is causing the error and I would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it, the reason for this was my Testrpc was not running, I hope this can help people in the future.